# How to pack whole ROS project

Tags: ros

I have made my ROS project down, and have tested the program successfully, then i need pack my project and give it to my customer.

I am confused about how to hide my source code and pack my whole ROS project into one application maybe, can anyone help me?

Comment: Googled a blog about this: http://erlerobotics.com/blog/ros-in-the-app-store/ hope it helps

Comment: You might want to checkout [bloom](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to create a shared object (that will hide all your source code).
This can be done in the CMakeList with `add_library`.
Once you have your `mystuff.so`, you can give it to your costumer (along with an example main.cpp and some documentation).
Your costumer will put a `target_link_library` in his CMakeList and will be able to use your stuff.